# plotting daily rainfall data using geom_step

Tags: r, date, ggplot2, posixct

I have some rainfall data collected continuously from which I have calculated daily totals. Here is some toy data:

```
Date <- c(seq(as.Date("2016-07-01"), by = "1 day", length.out = 10))
rain_mm <- c(3,6,8,12,0,0,34,23,5,1)
rain_data <- data.frame(Date, rain_mm)
```

I can plot this data as follows:

```
ggplot(rain_data, aes(Date, rain_mm)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%d")
```

Which gives the following:

[image]

This seems fine. It is clear how much rainfall there was on a certain day. However, it could also be interpreted that between midday of one day and midday of the next, a certain amount of rain fell, which is wrong. This is especially a problem if the graph is combined with other plots of related continuous variables over the same period.

To get round this issue I could use `geom_step` as follows:

```
library(ggplot)
ggplot(rain_data, aes(Date, rain_mm)) +
  geom_step() +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%d")
```

Which gives:

[image]

This is a better way to display the data, and now scale_x_date appears to be a continuous axis. However, it would be nice to get the area below the steps filled but cant seem to find a straight forward way of doing this.

**Q1: How can I fill beneath the geom_step? Is it possible?**

It may also be useful to convert `Date` into `POSIXct` to facilitate identical x-axis in multi-plot figures as discussed in this [SO question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39599584/ggplot2-differences-in-scale-x-date-and-scale-x-datetime).
I can do this as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
rain_data_POSIX <- rain_data %>% mutate(Date = as.POSIXct(Date))

                  Date rain_mm
1  2016-07-01 01:00:00       3
2  2016-07-02 01:00:00       6
3  2016-07-03 01:00:00       8
4  2016-07-04 01:00:00      12
5  2016-07-05 01:00:00       0
6  2016-07-06 01:00:00       0
7  2016-07-07 01:00:00      34
8  2016-07-08 01:00:00      23
9  2016-07-09 01:00:00       5
10 2016-07-10 01:00:00       1
```

However, this gives a time of 01:00 for each date. I would rather have 00:00. Can I change this in the `as.POSIXct` function call, or do I have to do it afterwards using a separate function? I think it is something to do with `tz = ""` but cant figure it out.

**How can I convert from class `Date` to `POSIXct` so that the time generated is 00:00?**

Thanks

Comment: First question is a potential duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21887088/generate-a-filled-geom-step

Comment: seconde question: try `tz="GMT"` or simply remove 1 hour: `as.POSIXct(Date) - 3600`..

Comment: @ArtemSokolov I had seen that but couldn't really figure the answers out. Also wanted to see if anything had changed recently. Thanks

Comment: @timat `tz="GMT"` doesn't have any affect, I get the same 01:00 time. I could just subtract an hours worth of seconds but it doesn't help with my understanding or use of the `as.POSIXct` function for longer code segments

Comment: @RoryShaw I added an edit to my response to your second question that adapts the linked example to your data with some additional explanations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your first question, you can work off [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41962072/300187). First, create a time-lagged version of your data:

```
rain_tl <- mutate( rain_data, rain_mm = lag( rain_mm ) )
```

Then combine this time-lagged version with the original data, and re-sort by date:

```
rain_all <- bind_rows( old = rain_data, new = rain_tl, .id="source" ) %>%
    arrange( Date, source )
```

(Note the newly created `source` column is used to break ties, correctly interlacing the original data with the time-lagged version):

```
> head( rain_all )
  source       Date rain_mm
1    new 2016-07-01      NA
2    old 2016-07-01       3
3    new 2016-07-02       3
4    old 2016-07-02       6
5    new 2016-07-03       6
6    old 2016-07-03       8
```

You can now use the joint matrix to "fill" your steps:

```
ggplot(rain_data, aes(Date, rain_mm)) +
  geom_step() +
  geom_ribbon( data = rain_all, aes( ymin = 0, ymax = rain_mm ),
             fill="tomato", alpha=0.5 ):
```

This produces the following plot:

[image]

---

For your second question, the problem is that [`as.POSIX.ct` does not pass additional arguments to the converter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6548795/300187), so specifying the `tz` argument does nothing.

You basically have two options:

1) Reformat the output to what you want: `format( as.POSIXct( Date ), "%F 00:00" )`, which returns a vector of type `character`. If you want to preserve the object type as `POSIXct`, you can instead...

2) Cast your `Date` vector to `character` prior to passing it to `as.POSIX.ct`: `as.POSIXct( as.character(Date) )`, but this will leave off the time entirely, which may be what you want anyway.

Comment: thanks for going through that. Looking at the `geom_bar` solution above, do you any idea why I cant specify a `width` argument when used in conjunction with `scale_x_datetime`?

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to avoid the hack, you can customize the position in the `geom_bar` expression.

I found good results with:

```
ggplot(rain_data, aes(Date, rain_mm)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_nudge(x = 0.51), width = 0.99) +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%d")
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, I was thinking along the same lines by converting `Date` to `POSIXct` and setting the time to 12:00. This makes it easier for me when aligning multiple plots with the same x-aixs. However, `geom_bar` doesn't appear to accept a `width` argument with `scale_x_datetime`...

Comment: Also looks better with `width = 1`

Comment: I didn't like the way `width = 1` looked. The slight partition is clean and shows a clear daybreak. But you have the tools you need now